# What's a coproduct in slice category?

Tags: category-theory

We know that product in slice category $\mathcal{C}\downarrow x$ is pullback in $\mathcal{C}$, but what's a coproduct in $\mathcal{C}\downarrow x$ (described in $\mathcal{C}$)? I tried to picture it as a limit or colimit, without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coproduct of $y \to x$ and $z \to x$ is $y \sqcup z \to x$. (Note that the forgetful functor from the slice category back down to $C$ has a right adjoint whenever $C$ has all products by $x$, and in that case it preserves all colimits. But actually it just always preserves all colimits.)

Comment: Is $\sqcup$ here a standard notation? How's it pronounced?

Comment: @Henning: I don't know how to pronounce it. It's reasonably standardish notation for coproducts, e.g. it's the notation used by both Wikipedia and the nLab.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the answer is that _if_ $y$ and $z$ have a coproduct in $\mathcal C$, then that coproduct induces a coproduct in the slice category? But if not, then the two arrows could still have a coproduct in the slice category.

Comment: @HenningMakholm doesn't that contradict the answer? If two arrows have a coproduct in a slice without their domains possesing a coproduct downstairs, then how can the projection preserve all colimits? Preservation would imply the existence of a coproduct downstairs.